# Optional GET parameter in Express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The following:

```
app.get('/foo/start/:start/end/:end', blah.someFunc);
```

matches

```
/foo/start/1/end/4
```

but I want it to also match an optional parameter

```
/foo/start/1/end/4/optional/7
```

I've tried this:

```
app.get('/foo/start/:start/end/:end(/optional/:value)?', blah.someFunc);
```

but it doesn't match either of the above two examples.  I think it's because I'm trying to give it a `RegExp` when it's expecting something else?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot mix paths with RegExps which is what you are doing.
Use either a path or a RegExp only.
http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB

Answer (score 22):

Why don't you add another rule before the one you have, like this

```
app.get('/foo/start/:start/end/:end/optional/:value', blah.someFunc);
app.get('/foo/start/:start/end/:end', blah.someFunc);
```

It will be used before the one without the optional value.

If you want to use just one line try this:

```
app.get('/foo/start/:start/end/:end/optional?', blah.someFunc)
```

see [the docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.route) for an example.

Comment: Yeh, I can do but I thought it would be cleaner to have one rule (if possible) :)

Comment: How much more? Do you have some data I can look at about this?

Comment: The hidden maintenance issue here is that ordering is important. If some misinformed dev comes along later and switches the ordering of your route definitions, your functionality just disappears.

You can handle this with one route using regular expressions, which is a standard feature of express.Router: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.VERB

Answer (score 19):

If you are using  Express 4.x Then I think its better to use array format for route.
For example I have route `/service` which gives all service list and same route when used with id `/service/id/:id` gives single service with id in the param.

```
app.get(['/service', '/service/id/:id'], function(req, res) {});
```

Comment: Clean answer, only question is can I avoid writing '/service' twice?

Comment: that need regular expression , this is clean.

Answer (score 6):

In this example, if the url is /hello or /hello/world it works. The ? makes the parameter become optional (express 4).

```
// app.js
var index = require('/routes/index');
app.use('/hello', index);

// routes/index.js
router.get('hello/:name?', function(req, res){
  var name = req.params.name;
  var data = {
    name: name
  };
  res.json(data);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use regular expressions in routes. Perhaps something like:

```
app.get(/^\/foo\/start\/:start\/end\/:end(\/optional\/:value)?/, function (req, res, next) {
```

Comment: This looks dirty dude :)

Comment: Why? Express translates *all* route strings to regular expressions. Using regexes directly is referred to all over the documentation: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#request

Comment: I know that, it was sarcasm.